# Date with bootsrap in 3 drop downs in form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue I have a form, where i would like to have a 3 drop downs for day / month / year, but all does drop down are placed big one under another but i would like to have it small and horizontal.

Any idea how to do it?

```
 <div class="form-group">
    Date:
        <Select ... />
        <Select ... />
        <Select ... />
 </div>
```

This gives me this:
[image]

But i would like to have it smaller and next to each other ...

Comment: please provide us the full `html` code you are using

Comment: Bootstrap recommends to **avoid** using `<select>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

you have to read bs3 [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

> Individual form controls automatically receive some global styling. All textual `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` elements with `.form-control` are set to `width: 100%;` by default. Wrap labels and controls in `.form-group` for optimum spacing.

this would work in your case:

```
<div class="form-group">
Date:
    <div class="col-xs-4"><select /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><select /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><select /></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use form-inline..

```
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
    Date:
    <select class="form-control"><option>One</option></select>
    <select class="form-control"><option>Two</option></select>
    <select class="form-control"><option>Three</option></select>
 </div>
 </form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/126815